# How do i detect new columns added to a list-view control?

Tags: delphi, events, listview

I am writing a component that descends from TListView, and I want to know when the developer using this component adds a column so I can react. How can I detect when a new column is added? Is there an event?

Comment: sorry for this... now its edited by RobKennedy. Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such event, but since you are the component writer, events are off-limits to you anyway. Events are for the developers *using* your component.

Columns are added by sending the control [`lvm_InsertColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761101.aspx) messages. Override that message handler in your descendant control:

```
procedure LVMInsertColumn(var Msg: TMessage); message lvm_InsertColumn;
```

Implement it to call the inherited handler, and then do whatever you want.

```
procedure TListViewDescendant.LVMInsertColumn(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  // TODO: custom handling
end;
```

Comment: will be called columncount + 1 times. Can be reduced to two calls by if  MSG.WParam + 1 = Columns.Count then // TODO: custom handling

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the `LVM_INSERTCOLUMN` message is sent, and then after that the column orders are updated, the column data is set and so on. You really want to get a look in when `UpdateColumns` has finished executing, but the design of `TListView` is not amenable to what @user is trying to do.

Comment: @user2025830 Remember that this applies only for column insertion. It does not apply to deletion, modification, or re-ordering of columns.

Answer (score 1):

The Delphi `TListView` control provides no such event, and the underlying Windows control does not provide a notification. The reason for that is that you the programmer are in charge of adding columns. Columns can only be added by calling `Columns.Add` in Delphi, or by sending a `LVM_INSERTCOLUMN` message to the underlying window.

So, you are in charge of adding columns, which presumably you do by calling `Columns.Add`. Route all code that adds columns through a method that calls `Columns.Add`, and add any special handling at that point.